# Make the personal statement on the careers profile draftable

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

For two reasons I'd like the personal statement to be made draftable i.e. you could save it and at some point and it's private, and then make it accessible to others later:

1. It's possibly the longest bit of writing you'll do on the profile, and you might want to take several attempts at it before letting someone see it.
2. To do this, I just left mine sitting there open, and of course I was asked to re-login on post, which promptly lost it.

Keeping another copy offline to work on until I'm ready to paste it into the box and post seems very back in the day and not very Stackish. Some will say that you'll probably take it from your CV, so it's a copy and paste job anyway, but I don't approach my profiles that way. Each one may be unique and tailored for the place (as in job site or agency) it will be used. StackCareers is different to many other careers sites, for example, I don't have to mention my Github repositories in my personal profile because they're listed. I don't get that option on a site like Reed, hence my personal profile is different.

So please, consider making it draftable.

Comment: Create an online accessible Google Doc an copy/paste that? That's what I did.

Comment: @Bart Sure, there's a thousand ways to do this that aren't the site, but my point is it's something that the Careers site should be doing (IMO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've tried in the past to make individual fields private/public which fit your use case. This became a a bulky feature that was difficult to maintain, and we got rid of it completely in early July.  You can make your profile private and unsearchable in the [privacy settings](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/privacy/) until you have a final personal statement.  We don't intend to allow individual sections to be marked private in the near future.

We will however look into saving as a draft your compositions in this section in case your browser crashes or you are logged out as you mentioned. This would be similar to how and answer auto-saves on Stack Exchange currently.

Comment: Forgive me if I wasn't clear, but I'm not asking for it to be customizable on and employer by employer basis. I'm asking for it to be draftable as it's a sizeable chunk of text, but after that then it's the same for everyone (aside from the caveats you gave). Where I spoke about tailored profiles, I meant that StackCareers may hold a different version to my one on for instance Reed, or on Monster or held in a local file - which means I'm unlikely to copy and paste from those to StackCareers.

Comment: Not your fault at all, I misread the request and edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Will, I appreciate your time on this.